# New HDD mounting and partitioning difficulties

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have recently purchased and installed a brand new 8TB Seagate Archive HDD into my desktop computer, and, using the "Disks" program in Ubuntu, I created one 8TB NFTS partition named "MediaStorage" and enabled mounting after booting.

From here I proceeded to transfer about ~1.5TB of data from both my internal HDD as well as from and external HDD to my new HDD.  Now, my computer is dual partitioned with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04, and after booting back into Ubuntu from Windows I realized the 8TB HDD wasn't mounting properly on its own.

In Ubuntu, I am able to mount the entire HDD an successfully access all files using "sudo mount /dev/sdb /path/to/location"; however I am unsure how to force it to mount automatically on boot for both Windows and Ubuntu.

Additionally, the same "Disks" program that I used to format/partition the 8TB HDD is now telling me that the partitioning of the drive is "Unknown()" and that there are 2 partitions both called "MediaStorage".  One is 871GB and the other is 372GB.

Ultimately I just want to have 1 partition that automatically mounts upon booting into either OS, and I would like to achieve this without having to rewrite all of the files I've already copied over if possible.  Perhaps there is a problem with the fstab or partitioning table, but I am unsure where to begin fixing this problem.  I have tried to find a solution, but I can't even think of a concise way to word this problem for a google search.

Any feedback, including problems with how I present this question would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the mounting is successful with `/dev/sdb`, meaning without a partition number, then you have created a filesystem on the whole disk without any partitions. This is not supported in Windows and is the reason why nothing is showing up. Also would explain why trying to read the partition info would result in strange results.

You will need to repartition the disk properly and retransfer the data to get it working correctly.

Comment: You might consider partitioning and formatting the drive from Windows. I think that will be more reliable. For instance, I can't remember ever having a problem mounting (Windows-formatted) ntfs drives in Linux. But, it seems like only a 50/50 chance of working the other way around.   Use `Start+R` then type: `diskmgmt.msc`. Windows will want to 'initialize' it, then create your partitions and format them. After that Windows will automatically pick it up at startup. Add an entry to '/etc/fstab' in Linux to automatically mount it there. --much envious about your 8TB drive, btw.. :-)

Comment: This definitely sounds like it could be it.  I guess I kinda rushed getting my HDD ready.  I'll give it a go when I have time.  Thanks guys!